# Couchbase sort options

Tags: go, couchbase, go-gin

I am using Go (1.10.3) with the Gin Framework. I am connecting to a Couchbase database (5.1.1) but I am having some issues with sorting the data.

So this is the code I am working with right now,

```
 //Build Search Sort
 func searchSort(c *gin.Context) (cbft.SearchSortField, *cbft.SearchSortScore, string) {
    mapData := getQuery(c)
    sortData := mapData["sort"]

    var sortType string
    var sortScore *cbft.SearchSortScore
    var sortOps *cbft.SearchSortField

    if sortData == "amount:asc" {
      fmt.Println( sortData )

      sortType = "asc"
      sortScore = cbft.NewSearchSortScore().Descending(false)
      sortOps = cbft.NewSearchSortField("AmountBase").Descending(false)
    }

   if sortData == "amount:desc" {
      fmt.Println( sortData )

      sortType = "desc"
      sortScore = cbft.NewSearchSortScore().Descending(true)
      sortOps = cbft.NewSearchSortField("AmountBase").Descending(true)

   }
   return sortOps, sortScore
}
```

Which I load into the query like so,

```
 sortOpsOne, sortOpsTwo := searchSort(c)

 ftSearch := gocb.NewSearchQuery("Search", searchOps).Sort(sortOpsOne).Sort(sortOpsTwo).Limit(size).Skip(from)
```

To explain, the above loads a get string request, e.g. `sort=amount:asc` to sort the JSON reply by the AmountBase field I have.

However this does not seem to be working at all, I started out with just the `sortOps` field but I added the `sortScore` field as the sort field was not doing anything.

Adding the `descending(false) / descending(true)` to the end of the sort field does not seem to do anything either.

The search is being run on a FTS index based from the data I have loaded into my bucket.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

It seems not to be working with descending options the ascending query seems to be working. :)

Comment: This might be more of a issue with Go Lang and or the drivers / libs I am importing. I am using a GVM to control the versions of Go I am running. I just did a test to move over to Go 1.11 and re-installed / go get all the imports again on that version. And from tests done, it looks like it might be working.