# Couchbase driver sort only sorts descending not ascending

Tags: go, full-text-search, couchbase, go-couchbase

Problem: the cbft will return to me a sorted result only when giving the `Descending` option a `true` value, for some reason when giving `false` it is not sorted (seems to be sorted based on `updated` but not the field I am looking for.
Here is my code:

```
var (
        qus []cbft.FtsQuery
    )
...

conjunction := cbft.NewConjunctionQuery(qus...)
q := gocb.NewSearchQuery(dd.Config.TrialsSearchIndex, conjunction)
sortBy := cbft.NewSearchSortField("drug_name").Descending(true) // if false does not sort
q.Sort(sortBy)
res, err := dd.Couchbase.TrialsBucket.ExecuteSearchQuery(q)
```

Why won't it sort in ascending order?

Comment: This seems to be a persistent (never solved or reported to the driver developers) issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441180/couchbase-sort-options

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the issue was with the way the field was being parsed, Couchbase allows placing **custom analyzers** on a field, if you need to use the same field in a text search where say you need to parse multiple words and in a case like here just retrieving in Alphabetical order you will need to define an *alias* on the field and put a different analyzer for that field. In this case I set the anlyzer to "single" (i.e. to parse the field as ONE word) and to filter everything as to be lowercase insensitive.
Basically create an **alias** for the field `field_sort` and a **custom analyzer**.
You can read more about writing analyzers here:  https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/fts/fts-using-analyzers.html
The documentation leaves what to be desired but hopefully this helps someone.